# Custom Facelet component in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

Is it possible to create a custom JSF core Facelet component. Something like `<custom:composition>` of `<ui:composition>`, or `<custom:include>` for `<ui:include>`
It would be helpful if someone can tell me the steps involved.

Thanks in advance,

Kaushal

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It are in essence taghandlers. I.e. classes extending from [`TagHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/TagHandler.html).

Here's a Hello World taghandler.

`com.example.HelloTagHandler`

```
public class HelloTagHandler extends TagHandler {

    public HelloTagHandler(TagConfig config) {
        super(config);
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(FaceletContext context, UIComponent parent) throws IOException {
        // Do your job here. This example dynamically adds another component to the parent.
        if (ComponentHandler.isNew(parent)) {
            UIOutput child = new HtmlOutputText();
            child.setValue("Hello World");
            parent.getChildren().add(child);
        }

        nextHandler.apply(context, parent); // Delegate job further to first next tag in tree hierarchy.
    }

}
```

`/WEB-INF/my.taglib.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0"
>
    <namespace>http://example.com/my</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>hello</tag-name>
        <handler-class>com.example.HelloTagHandler</handler-class>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

`/WEB-INF/web.xml` (note: this part is not mandatory when `my.taglib.xml` is in `/META-INF` folder of a JAR file inside `/WEB-INF/lib` like as with JSF component libraries):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/my.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Usage in `/some.xhtml`

```
<html ... xmlns:my="http://example.com/my">
...
<my:hello />
```

To see the source code of Mojarra implementation of [`<ui:composition>`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.11/com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/ui/CompositionHandler.java/) and [`<ui:include>`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.11/com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/ui/IncludeHandler.java), click the links.

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

Comment: Thanks for the example. It was indeed helpful. I must say that your answers for JSF are very valuable.

Comment: I'm using this strategy, and I noticed that on a postback, the created component is moved, becoming the first child of the parent. Frustrating...