# Dynamically set the event of an a4j:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, literals

When trying to dynamically set the `event` of an `a4j:ajax` as follow:

```xml
<a4j:ajax event="#{myBean.event}" listener="#{myBean.listener}" />
```

I get the following error:

```
<a4j:ajax> The 'event' attribute for behavior tag must be a literal
```

It seems to come from [`javax.faces.view.facelets.BehaviorHandler`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.1.4/javax/faces/view/facelets/BehaviorHandler.java):

```java
public BehaviorHandler(BehaviorConfig config) {
    super(config);
    this.behaviorId = config.getBehaviorId();
    this.event = this.getAttribute("event");
    if (null != event && !event.isLiteral()) {
        throw new TagException(this.tag, "The 'event' attribute for behavior tag must be a literal");
    }
}
```

I would like to write my own `CustomBehaviorHandler` to make it behave as I need. The question is: how to register this new `CustomBehaviorHandler` with JSF?

Or is there any other way to suit my needs?

I can't find any example nor documentation about it, but it seems to be possible, since PrimeFaces has its own [org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorHandler](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/behavior/ajax/AjaxBehaviorHandler.java?r=6605).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I would like to write my own CustomBehaviorHandler to make it behave as I need. The question is: how to register this new CustomBehaviorHandler with JSF?*

You'd need to create a custom tag for that. Prepare a `*.taglib.xml` as demonstrated in this answer: [Custom Facelet component in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006955/custom-facelet-component-in-jsf/15007720#15007720) (note: taghandler class is not necessary) and add the following entry:

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>ajax</tag-name>
    <behavior>
        <behavior-id>com.example.MyAjaxBehavior</behavior-id>
        <handler-class>com.example.MyAjaxBehaviorHandler</handler-class>
    </behavior>
    <!-- Define attributes here. -->
</tag>
```

Then you'll be able to use `<my:ajax>`. Note: you've got to reimplement a lot in the behavior handler class; you can't simply extend from `BehaviorHandler` as it throws the exception during its construction already.

---

> *Or is there any other way to suit my needs?*

Depends on concrete functional requirement for which you thought that *this* would be the solution. This is unfortunately not stated anywhere in the question, so I can't answer that part.

---

> *I can't find any example nor documentation about it, but it seems to be possible, since PrimeFaces has its own org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorHandler.*

That's the `<p:ajax>`. The `<a4j:ajax>` which you've initially at your hands is also such one, by the way.

Comment: Wow, you're right, it's harder than I thought... Actually, I find that .xhtml files become quickly overloaded. I wanted to try a [Java-managed View](http://pastebin.com/VqWHFSxi). Then, within the JSF beans, simply [instantiate a new View](http://pastebin.com/GgnmRMwp), and using [custom tags](http://pastebin.com/L8b2bBRc), write [only few lines](http://pastebin.com/7PKHku1M) in your .xhtml files. But it seems to be a bit utopian, and I'm not sure about the benefits of such a system (it was more about the technical challenge actually ;) So if you have any trail... Thanks anyway!

Comment: I see. If you go that path, you could perhaps add them programmatically via  `ClientBehaviorHolder#addClientBehavior(String, AjaxBehavior)`.